# How to prevent selection of date values beyond today's date?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As shown below in the HTML code, I have a date-picker. I want to set the max and min values of the date programmatically from the typescript code. I want to set the min and the max values of the date so that the user cannot select any date beyond the max
value set, and cannot select any date below the min value set.

The desired value for the `[max]` should be today's date.

I tried the following approach, but still, the user can select a date value greater than today's date.

```
this.maxDateLimit = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en')
```

Please let me know how to correct this.

**Html**:

```html
<div id="idDateOfSprayContainer">
    <clr-date-container class="clsDateContainer">
        <label id="idDateOfSprayLabel">
            {{ "SITE.INSECTICIDES.DATE_OF_SPRAY_LABEL" | translate }}:
        </label>
        <input id="idDateOfSprayValue" class="clr-control-container" clrDate type="date" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfSpray"  name="dateOfSpray" (ngModelChange)="onDateOfSpraySet($event)"
                value="2021-07-21" [min]="minDateLimit" [max]="maxDateLimit" [disabled] = "!siteSelectionState"/>
    </clr-date-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try like this? ```maxDateLimit  = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)```

Comment: @NarayanDeshmukh i tried it and it did not change any thing unfortunately!

Answer (score 3):

Always we use a library, we need take account the "Inputs" of the component and the type of this Inputs.

In the case of clarity date-picker you see the "Inputs" in "Summary of Options" of the [docs](https://clarity.design/documentation/datepicker) (at the end of the document)

See that the "min" and "max" inputs are strings in the way "yyyy-MM-dd"

So checking the [custom format option in Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options)

```
this.maxDateLimit = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd','en-US')
```

NOTE: I use the local "en-US" because if the installed by defect in Angular -we needn't add any local more-. In this case it's indiferent use 'en-US' than, e.g. if we added locale-es for Spanish 'es-ES'

Comment: I tried the answer you posted but unfortunately it did not solve the issue

Comment: unfortunately, i still able to select dates greater than today's date

Answer (score 1):

Withour prior knowledge of angular, I was able to come up with this by reading the documentation and some trial and error:

```js
angular.module("date", [])
  .controller("controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.today = function() {
      return new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="date" ng-controller="controller">
  <form>
    <input type="date" max="{{today()}}" />
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

Dates beyond today cannot be selected:

[image]

You can enter a later date by typing in, for example, `12/31/2050`, but you will then see an error message when you submit the form:

[image]

Note that I did not put `max` in square brackets.

Comment: I checked the example you provided…still exists the problem, because I can select dates farther than today’s..I want please to be able to deactivate any dates beyond today’s date so the user can not select it

Comment: By the time I tested it, there was no submit button

Comment: Yes, I added that only after reading your helpful comment.

Comment: So do you think when I change my code to include the ‘max’ value to be as follows: max="{{today()}}. It will work as it works in your  code ?

Comment: You must also define the controller like I did.

Comment: The OP is not using Angular 1.x, so they won't be creating the controller like you did.  There are no controllers in Angular 2+

Answer (score 1):

[image]You should use min & max like this for your case.

> ```
> [min]="minDateLimit | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [max]="maxDateLimit | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'".
> ```

This is the angualr Date Pipe.For more info on date pipe you can visit angualr documentation link https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Date pipe will convert to the value binded to our required format.
As other member pointed out that it should be in string format only.

> In the case of clarity date-picker you see the "Inputs" in "Summary of
> Options" of the docs (at the end of the document)

```
    this.minDateLimit = (formatDate(new Date("2023-06-04"), 'yyyy-MM-dd ', 'en'));
    this.maxDateLimit = (formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd ', 'en')) ;//new Date means it will get current date as per your requirment
```

Comment: @Amrmsmb Have you checked this solution?If not working Pls try to add some more details or a snippet.

Comment: unfortunately, i still able to select dates greater than today's date

Comment: Can u add a stackblitz example.I have tried and it worked perfectly.

Comment: try : maxDateLimit = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);

Comment: See this link if it helps: https://github.com/vmware-archive/clarity/issues/4184

Answer (score 0):

Setting the max value from javascript works as per the expectation. Checkout the working example

```js
var maxDateLimit = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

document.getElementById("idDateOfSprayValue").max = maxDateLimit;
```

```html
<div id="idDateOfSprayContainer">
    <clr-date-container class="clsDateContainer">
        <label id="idDateOfSprayLabel">
        </label>
        <input id="idDateOfSprayValue" class="clr-control-container" clrDate type="date" placeholder="" name="dateOfSpray"/>
    </clr-date-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [Date Picker docs](https://clarity.design/documentation/datepicker#examples) from Clarity Design there mentioned the following guideline in the examples section.

> We recommend that you either access the date as a string or as a javascript date object from the date picker. Using both at the same time might cause unexpected behavior.

Maybe you can experiment passing in `Date` objects instead for all the `Input` directives in the date picker input, or map all date variables in the component file to strings of the same format.

For `Date` objects you can use `new Date()` or `Date.parse` function (this returns a timestamp number). For string objects you can use the pipe operator from Angular like `[min]="new Date() | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"` using the accepted placeholder formats in the Date Picker docs.