# YYYY-MM-DD is not a valid format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

referring to this link:https://clarity.design/documentation/datepicker
in the last section titled `Summary of Options`, it states that, for example, `[max]` should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` formate.

as shown in the below posted code, i set the same format to `maxDateLimit`. but when run the code, i receive the logs shown in the screen-shot.

Am I using `YYYY-MM-DD` wongly? please let me know why i am getting this error and how to fix it

**code**:

```
private onSatelliteTimeRangeFromSet(event:any):void {
console.log(this.debugTag,"dateOfSpray: ", this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray)
const splitted = this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray.split('/')
const numOfDateBites = splitted.length
this.maxDateLimit = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as string
const maxDateLimitAsDate = new Date(this.maxDateLimit)
const dateOfSprayAsDate = new Date(this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray)
const maxDateDate = maxDateLimitAsDate.getDate()
const maxDateMonth = maxDateLimitAsDate.getMonth()
const maxDateYear = maxDateLimitAsDate.getFullYear()

console.log(this.debugTag,"maxDateLimit: ", this.maxDateLimit)
```

**logs**

[image]

Comment: In the [docs related](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options) you see the "custom format options". See that year are `yyyy` and day `dd` (both in lowercase). In the clarity doc's only say that you need use a string with the fullYear, the month and the day of the month.

Comment: NOTE: From Angular 12, you can use the formatDate function directly: `this.maxDateLimit = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyy-MM-dd','en-US')`, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76873436/how-to-prevent-selection-of-date-values-beyond-todays-date/76873888#76873888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the issue below.

Try lowercase `yyyy` rather than uppercase `YYYY`?

[how to convert current date to YYYY-MM-DD format with angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630445/how-to-convert-current-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-with-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues :

- You're using `YYYY` which is the "week numbering year", you need to use `yyyy`
- `DD` has no value, you need to use `dd` to get the date.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. DD to `dd` (small)
2. YYYY to `yyyy` (small)